# Unable to get all links from the webpage - Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

Unable to get all links from the webpage - Selenium
Unable to get all links from the webpage by using below mentioned code.
Code below:

```
package config;



import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class ActionKeywords {
//  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void setup()
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "E:\\geckodriver-v0.16.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        dc.setCapability("marionette", true);
        driver =  new FirefoxDriver(dc);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    @Test
    public void openBrowser(){
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
    }



/*
@Test
    public void verify_Menus(){

        WebElement mainMenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='menu-main']/li/a"));
        System.out.println(mainMenu.getText());
        WebElement subMenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Impegno Per La Natura')]"));
        Actions action = new Actions (driver);
        action.moveToElement(mainMenu).perform();
        System.out.println(subMenu.getText());
        action.click(subMenu).perform();
    } */

    @Test
    public void all_Links(){
        try{
        List<WebElement> allLinks = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        System.out.println("Count of all links: " +allLinks.size());

        //Loop
        for (WebElement link : allLinks)
            System.out.println(link.getText());


    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Element not found by tagName");
    }
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void close_Browser(){
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

After run this program, result displayed as 'Count of all links: 0'
Please advise!

Thanks,
Sudhir

Answer (score 0):

You will get all links using containing the attributes href / src like shown in following code:

```
@Test
    public void alllinks()
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:/Selenium/Drivers/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.get("http://www.google.com");

    List<WebElement> list=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@href or @src]"));

    for(WebElement e : list){
        String link = e.getAttribute("href");
        if(null==link)
            link=e.getAttribute("src");
        System.out.println(e.getTagName() + "=" + link);
    }
    }
```

Hope this code will help you.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are using the correct code But executing in wrong order all_Links() method is executing first before openBrowser().
Please put the priority in your @test annotation because @test annotation  run by default alphabetical order.

Hope this will helpful to you!!!

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you can change `driver.get("https://www.google.com/");` from `OpenBrowser()` to `SetUp()`. `OpenBrowser()` is not supposed to be a test and it can be interfering with the order of execution.